# Formulate constraints to an Integer programming: How to algebraically formulate a geometric constraint that the colored grids must form a rectangle?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am stuck in a constraint formulation of a discrete optimization problem. Consider a board of Cartesian grids (M rows by N columns). We are going to color some grids among them. There is a geometric constraint that the colored grids must form a rectangle (and its interior, no holes).

My question is: How to algebraically formulate this geometric constraint (so that it can be handled by computer)?

The decision variables can be written as $x_i, i\in \{1,2,\ldots,M\cdot N\}$. $x_i=1$ if the $i$th grid is colored; $x_i=0$ if the $i$th grid is not colored. (Or since the board is 2D, for convenience, you can use a two-digit index to denote a decision variable, for example, $x_{ij}=1$ if the grid located at $i$th row and $j$th column is colored, now $i\in \{1,2,\ldots,M\}$ and $j\in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}$)

A sketch to help you understand the question:
[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6yeu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to enforce
$$(x_i \land x_j) \implies x_k,$$
where $1\le i<j \le M\cdot N$ and $k$ is within the rectangle determined by $i$ and $j$.  Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$
(x_i \land x_j) \implies x_k \\
\lnot (x_i \land x_j) \lor x_k \\
\lnot x_i \lor \lnot x_j \lor x_k,
$$
from which we obtain linear constraint
$$(1-x_i) + (1-x_j) + x_k \ge 1,$$
equivalently,
$$x_i + x_j - x_k \le 1.$$

---

Update to match your two-indexed variables:
$$x_{i_1,j_1} + x_{i_2,j_2} - x_{i_3,j_3} \le 1,$$
for all $(i_1,j_1)$, $(i_2,j_2)$, and $(i_3,j_3)$ such that
$(i_3,j_3)$ is in the rectangle determined by $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$.
That is,
$$\min(i_1,i_2) \le i_3 \le \max(i_1,i_2) \text{ and } \min(j_1,j_2) \le j_3 \le \max(j_1,j_2).$$
Alternatively, you can avoid duplicate constraints by imposing lexicographic ordering of $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$ as follows:
$$(i_1 < i_2 \lor (i_1 = i_2 \land j_1 < j_2)) \land (i_1 \le i_3 \le i_2)  \land (\min(j_1,j_2) \le j_3 \le \max(j_1,j_2)).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't think it is that simple. 1) my question is two-dimensional, thus your constraint doesn't apply to it;  2) i, j, k should be free index (not dummy), then how to identify the ranges of i, j, k, does it hold for any two i \in 1...M, j \in 1...N?

Comment: I initially used one-indexed variables $x_i$ to match your question.  Now that you have used two-indexed variables $x_{i,j}$, I updated my answer.  The logic is the same, no matter what indexing you use: if two grids are colored, every grid in the corresponding rectangle must also be colored.

Comment: Thanks.......... The indexes i, j are free variables, right? This means, e.g., i ranges from 1 through M to obtain all the constraints?.................. Also, could you please clarify how to convert the logical expression to the algebraic expression,  just like what you did in your old-version answer.

Comment: Yes, $\{(i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2),(i_3,j_3)\}\subset\{1,\dots,M\}\times\{1,\dots,N\}$.

Comment: Also, could you please clarify how to convert the logical expression to the algebraic expression (I mean you write two expressions in your updated-version answer, are they equivalent?),  just like what you did in your old-version answer? You could directly write the derivation in your answer. I don't know how to address function "min/max" in the constraint.

Comment: Dear Rob, your answer is helpful!    But I found you have changed the expression of indexes i_1, i_2, i_3 ......, now it reads "min<=i_3<=max and min<=j_3<=max". Could you pls also add the expression of indexes you wrote last time to the latest answer ( I can remember you used lexicographical order in that version)?  I would also like to learn that expression since it is beautiful I think.  Thanks!!

Comment: I had removed that part because I thought it might have been confusing you, but I have now appended it to the answer.  If you are satisfied, please mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks! Now I totally know what you mean. It's not the logical expression of the constraints, but the range of free indexes.

Comment: Dear Rob, a minor question to follow up: in addition to (xi∧xj)⟹xk, k inside the rectangle, do I still need to add (xi∧xj)⟹~xl (~means negation,  l is outside the rectangle bounded by x_i and x_j) as another constraint?  Because I need to ensure that not only the grids inside the rectangle are colored, but also the the grids outside the rectangle are NOT colored. ....Or is this a duplicate constraint since (xi∧xj)⟹xk, k inside is strong enough ?

Comment: No, you do not need another constraint, and what you suggested would be too strong because the grids corresponding to $x_i$ and $x_j$ might be in the interior and you don't want to exclude grids on the border of the rectangle.